# how to replace all the items of array by indexes of specified lists?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I want to replace all the items of `sequence` with ids that tell which list of labeller they are in. Assume that all the values are distinct in both `sequence` and `labeller` and a union of lists of `labeller` has the same items as `sequence`. `lsizes` corresponds to the sizes of lists in `labeller` and is redundant for Pythonic solution but might be compulsory for solution to be vectorised fully.

```
sequence = [1, 2, 10, 5, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 9],
labeller = [[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
lsizes = [3, 5, 2]
```

I know how to solve it in a simple way:

```
idx = {u:i for i, label in enumerate(labeller) for u in label}
tags = [idx[u] for u in sequence]
```

And the output is:

```
tags = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

After that I put all my efforts to do it in vectorised way. It's quite complicated for me. This is my attempt, done rather by a guess, but, unfortunately, it doesn't pass all my tests. I hope I'm close:

```
sequence = np.array(sequence)
cl = np.concatenate(labeller)
_, cl_idx = np.unique(cl, return_index=True)
_, idx = np.unique(sequence[cl_idx], return_index=True)
tags = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lsizes)), lsizes)[idx]
#output: [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2]
```

How can I finish it? I would also like to see rigour explanation what it does and how to understand it better. Any sources are also welcome.

Comment: Honestly I think the python approach is not that bad. Would be interested in vectorized solution with pure numpy as well. Although since your data are pure python lists, the runtime overhead to covert them into numpy array might already be almost the same with that of the pure python solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

For those tracing back problems, [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) seems to be the way to go and works here too, re-using your `cl` -

```
cl = np.concatenate(labeller)
sidx = cl.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(cl, sequence, sorter=sidx)
idx0 = sidx[idx]

l = list(map(len, labeller))
r = np.repeat(np.arange(len(l)), l)
out = r[idx0]
```

Using `lsizes` for `l` makes it fully vectorized. But, I suspect the concatenation step might be heavy. Whether this is worth it or not would depend a lot on the lengths of the subarrays.

**Approach #2**

For positive numbers, here's one with array-indexing as a hashing mechanism -

```
N = max(map(max, labeller))+1
id_ar = np.zeros(N, dtype=int) # use np.empty for perf. boost
for i,l in enumerate(labeller):
    id_ar[l] = i
out = id_ar[sequence]
```

Comment: I am curious if this can top the python approach if performance is the goal. Is this faster (even if the overhead of converting to arrays is not considered)?

Comment: @Ehsan I would think app#2 would, given that it skips the second loop when compared against given Python soln. On app#1, I am hopeful, if we skip considering concatenation part, given enough number of subarrays.

Comment: I also think the second one is a better hashing than the original one proposed in question if the values are not too large for memory issue. I was curious about the numpyic approach vs. pythonic one.

Answer (score 2):

```
sequence = [1, 2, 10, 5, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 9]
labeller = [[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
lsizes = [3, 5, 2]

sequence_array = np.array(sequence)
labeller_array = np.array(labeller).sum()
index_array = np.repeat(list(range(len(lsizes))), lsizes)

np.apply_along_axis(lambda num : index_array[np.where(labeller_array == num)[0]], 0, sequence_array[None, :])
# output: array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

Alternative:

```
label_df = pd.DataFrame({'label':labeller_array, 'index':index_array})
seq_df = pd.DataFrame({'seq':sequence_array})
seq_df.merge(label_df, left_on = 'seq', right_on = 'label')['index'].tolist()
#output: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```